# Hylafax/Postfix routing emails that are not fax numbers

Tags: email, postfix, fax

I have a Postfix / Hylafax system for email-to-fax however I need to prevent emails that are NOT of the form

```
<phonenumber>@fax.mydomain.com
```

to be forwarded on by email.
How do I do this or where is that configured? 
Or is there a method for transport mapping one or two standard user addresses?

My current /etc/postfix/transport file:

```
fax.mydomain.com fax:localhost
```

My current /etc/postfix/master.cf:

```
fax     unix    -       n       n       -       -       pipe    flags= user=fax argv=/usr/bin/faxmail -d -n -N -T ${user}
```

Answer (score 1):

I added the users to the /etc/postfix/transport file that I wanted to forward to standard local mail instead of my Hylafax server above the line for faxes.

```
user@fax.mydomain.com    local:localhost
root@fax.mydomain.com    local:localhost
FaxMaster@host.mydomain.com    local:localhost
fax.mydomain.com    fax:localhost
```

Then updated the postfix table and restarted postfix:

```
sudo /usr/sbin/postmap /etc/postfix/transport 
sudo service postfix restart
```